# I would like to change jid for ejabberd account

Tags: ejabberd-api

I would like to change jid for ejabberd account. My purpose for changing account jid is to change mobile number of user. My all accounts jid is the telephone number of customer. So for some purpose the user is changing his telephone number.

So I need to link all his chat to new telephone number. I had check ejabberd API's but not found any way to do that. So is there any way to do same?

Answer (score 0):

There is no command to perform all the tasks that would be required:
1. Edit table 'passwd' or 'users', to rename the username
2. Edit table 'roster', and rename the username of the roster items of your user.
3. Search in all the rosters of other users, and replace the username of the contact.

For 2 and 3, you can try getting the old information with process_rosteritems, and then pushing new information with push_roster.
For 1, you can do it manually.